# Recycle Fragment Views when using ViewPager (Mvvmcross)

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using a ViewPager in an Mvvmcross Android App. The Fragments inside the ViewPager are all of the same kind. Is there a possibility to use some view recycling to avoid inflating a new view when scrolling through the ViewPager?

Comment: Use ViewPager2 and your own adapter, which is super similar to RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: Is there some example available how to do this using Mvvmcross?